# How do I put a Conv1D layer after an Embedding layer in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

For an evaluation, I need to be able to apply a convolutional layer to text data. So I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis on Amazon reviews. After the `Embedding` layer, however, the `Conv1D` layer will not get the required shape.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
print(f'Tensorflow version {tf.__version__}')
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Embedding
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k',
                                          split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST],
                                          as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

padded_shapes = ([None], ())

train_dataset = train_data.shuffle(25000).padded_batch(padded_shapes=padded_shapes, batch_size=16)
test_dataset = test_data.shuffle(25000).padded_batch(padded_shapes=padded_shapes, batch_size=16)

n_words = info.features['text'].encoder.vocab_size


class ConvModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvModel, self).__init__()
        self.embe = Embedding(n_words, output_dim=16)
        self.conv = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=6, activation='elu')
        self.glob = GlobalAveragePooling1D()
        self.dens = Dense(2)

    def call(self, x, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.embe(x)
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.glob(x)
        x = self.dens(x)
        return x

conv = ConvModel()

conv(next(iter(train_data))[0])
```

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_25 is incompatible with the layer: 
>       expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [163, 16]

How is it possible to achieve this, and if I'm wrong, what is the proper way to use a `Conv1D` layer to text sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `conv(next(iter(train_dataset))[0])` and not `conv(next(iter(train_data))[0])`

the network structure is ok

Answer (score 0):

you have done it so far so good. The last line of the code should be changed. That's all. The parameter should be train_data not the train_dataset.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
print(f'Tensorflow version {tf.__version__}')
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Embedding
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k',
                                          split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST],
                                          as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

padded_shapes = ([None], ())

train_dataset = train_data.shuffle(25000).padded_batch(padded_shapes=padded_shapes, batch_size=16)
test_dataset = test_data.shuffle(25000).padded_batch(padded_shapes=padded_shapes, batch_size=16)

n_words = info.features['text'].encoder.vocab_size


class ConvModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvModel, self).__init__()
        self.embe = Embedding(n_words, output_dim=16)
        self.conv = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=6, activation='elu')
        self.glob = GlobalAveragePooling1D()
        self.dens = Dense(2)

    def call(self, x, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.embe(x)
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.glob(x)
        x = self.dens(x)
        return x

conv = ConvModel()

conv(next(iter(train_data))[0])
```

Hope you fix the error.

Comment: Hi. This solution has been suggested already, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

The out_dim of word embedding layer should match with conv1D input filter size. Try changing the out_dim to 32. Proper way: https://machinelearningmastery.com/predict-sentiment-movie-reviews-using-deep-learning/